# Can we create a sound wave only rarefactions or only compressions?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, air

We all know that sound waves consists of a rarefaction and a compression, but can we a sound wave consists of only rarefactions or only compression.

Answer (score 1):

The medium is rarefied or compressed relative to its mean pressure. Therefore if there are compressions, there must also be rarefactions. And we have to have pressure variation in order for there to be a longitudinal wave.

Comment: Not necessarily. Conceptually compressions can be followed by ever stronger compressions thus creating pressure variations sufficient for the wave to propagate. Naturally, this would work only for a limited time, but it is possible.

Comment: i agree with safesphere

Comment: Isn't the 'even stronger compression' an extension of the original compression?

Comment: I think safesphere means, as he says, the sound will get more compression from a zero start of a flat transducer diaphragm being increasingly distorted. Same with my balloon example.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia [Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound)

> As the source continues to vibrate the medium, the vibrations propagate away from the source at the speed of sound, thus forming the sound wave.

If you put a ballon, say close to your ear canal, you might well hear the sound, before the vibration you describe is set up. So just compressions, would do it. Acoustic energy is transmitted.